# How to store value of data binding expression into variable

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, binding

I need to access the value of a bound item several times in a template. Right now my ListView template looks like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plc"><br/>
 <ItemTemplate><br/>
  <input type="radio" class="myrating<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%>" value="3" /><br/>
  <input type="radio" class="myrating<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%>" value="4" /><br/>
    </ItemTemplate><br/>
    <LayoutTemplate><br/>
        <div id="plc" runat="server"><br/>
        </div><br/>
    </LayoutTemplate><br/>
    <EmptyDataTemplate><br/>
        No data</EmptyDataTemplate><br/>
</asp:ListView><br/>
```

Under certain conditions I may have dozens of radio button so repeatedly calling `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%>` seems to be inefficient.

I would like to assign the value of that expression to a variable and then use this variable instead so my template would look something like this

```
<ItemTemplate><br />
<%String ClassName = "myrating" + <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%><br />
  <input type="radio" class="<%=ClassName %>" value="3" /><br />
  <input type="radio" class="<%="ClassName" value="4" /><br />
    </ItemTemplate><br />
```

This example doesn't compile but I hope you are getting the idea.

Comment: Are there specific performance problems or do you just think doing an Eval repeatedly is going to be a problem?

You could always set the class of the radio buttons in the ItemDataBound event of the list view.

Comment: I haven't profiled it yet but I think calling Eval repeatedly to get the same value will be wasteful and also harder to maintain. 
Using ItemDataBound would work but it would be nice if there ware a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, and yeah... doing an Eval repeatedly is a BIG problem (for my application) considering the database hits involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OnItemDataBount` event and work with DataItem as with variable there.

Answer (score 4):

You can give your page a public variable MyRating.

Now you can assign the variable in the expression binding Syntax:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
         <%# MyRating = "myrating" + <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%>
         //Use the variable inside the binding(!) block 
         <%#MyRating
   </ItemTemplate>
```

I usually bind to lists of view-objects. That way I can access view properties directly.

```
   <ItemTemplate>
         <%# MyType = (MyType)Container.DataItem 
         <%# MyRating.Average %> 
         <%# MyRating.Count %> 
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Neither of your code examples work for me in VS2010 using ASP.NET 4. Is this something that used to work but no longer works? Putting data-binding expressions inside data-binding expressions generates syntax errors for me.

Comment: Also, `<%# MyRating = "myrating" + <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day")%>` causes the resulting value of `MyRating` to be output in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I personally consider setting HTML element values in the `OnItemDataBound` event to be messier than in the ASP code. I also didn't like setting the variable value using a data-binding expression since it seems to cause the value to be output in the HTML.

Here's a similar way to do it based on the other answers:

### 1. Create a protected field in the code-behind to use as your variable.

```
protected string className;
```

### 2. Use a data-binding expression to assign to the variable.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="false" Text="<%# className = "myrating" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Day") %>" />
```

**Make sure to do this inside the hidden server-side tag so that the result of the expression does not appear in the resulting HTML.**

### 3. Use the variable inside data-binding expressions in the ASP code.

```
<ItemTemplate><br />
    <input type="radio" class="<%# className %>" value="3" /><br />
    <input type="radio" class="<%# className %>" value="4" /><br />
</ItemTemplate><br />
```

**Make sure to use data-binding expressions to access the variable. Other expression types only seem to see the  default value of the variable.**

I think the main disadvantage of this approach is the use of the field, which would ideally be scoped to the `ItemTemplate` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can define public/protected variables in the code-behind and assign those in data binding expressions.

If you don't have access to the code-behind (e.g. when you are modifying the markup of a compiled application), you can declare variables in a `script` block set to run on server, e.g.:

```
<script runat="server">
    YourNamespace.Rating current;
</script>
```

Then in your control's binding templates:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <%# (current = (YourNamespace.Rating)Eval("Day")) == null ? "" : "" %>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Put it in the `HeaderTemplate` if you only want it to get executed once per databinding.
The `== null ? "" : ""`-part, is to prevent any generated cruft html (e.g. the `ToString` value of the assigned value), from being rendered in the browser.